# Rails hash and arrays

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, hash

I am making a timesheet, but i have problems.
I want it to look like this:

```
projects   |Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday Sunday 

development| 3:50   4:00    5:00       3:00   0:00    0:00     0:00

Testing    | 0:00   0:00    0:00       2:00   4:00    0:00     0:00

Lanch      | 0:00   0:00    0:00       0:00   1:00    6:00     0:00
```

Every project has_many logs with hours as a field.

I did this query:

```
@log_week_project = current_user.logs.where(:log_date => (Time.now.beginning_of_week + 1.second)..(Time.now.end_of_week - 1.second)).group("project_id").group("date(log_date)").sum(:hours)
```

And get this:

```
<OrderedHash {[2, "2011-05-24"]=>31800.0, [1, "2011-05-24"]=>10200.0, [1, "2011-05-23"]=>25200.0, [1, "2011-05-26"]=>19800.0}>
```

The key in the hash is an array with the project_id @ [0] and log_date @ [1]. The value is the hours.

I do this in my view:

```
<% for project in @projects do %>
  <%= project.name %>
  <%  @log_week_project.map do |key,hours|%>
    <% if key[0] == project.id %>
      <%= time_diff(hours)%>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This gives me the project hours on each date, but if there is a date with no hours there is no output and the table gets wrong.

If there is no hours on wednesday the thursday hours ends up in the wednesday column.

Any tips on how to do this? Perhaps there is a better way?

**SOLUTION:**

Thanks for replies and comments. The solution was:

```
<% for project in @projects do %>
<%= project.name %>
<% @dates.each do |date| %>
<%  hours = @log_week_project.detect { |key| key[0][0].to_i == project.id && key[0][1].to_time.strftime('%a') == date.to_time.strftime('%a')}%>     
        <%= hours ? time_diff(hours[1]) : "0:00"%>
    <% end %>
```

<% end %>

Where @dates is an array of the dates in the timerange. Now refactoring... ; )

Comment: What if a current_user.logs.first.log_date == Time.now.beginning_of_week? This will be missed in your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this:

```
<% for project in @projects do %>
  <%= project.name %>
  <% (1..7).each do |day| %>
    <% date = "2011-05-#{22 + day}" #please modify this, this is only to keep the example simple %> 
      <% hours = @log_week_project.detect{|key| key[0] == project && key[1] == date } %>
        "<%= hours ? time_diff(hours) : "" %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

next, refactor this to put all the logic in a helper.
Hope, that helps

Comment: Thanks for good suggestion. I did not get anything when I tried it. so I tried `<% hours = @log_week_project.detect{|key| key[0].to_i == project.id && key[1] == date } %>` And got this error `undefined method `to_i' for [1, "2011-05-23"]:Array`

Comment: I'd do this differently, but your issue with the to_i on the Array is because the detect is on A Hash... which needs |key, value|... where the key in this case is an array.

Answer (score 0):

In your database you may have 0 as default for all hours, that way it can't be blank.

But if you storing hours in logs, then you can't do above. In that case, use

```
 time_diff(hours).present? ? time_diff(hours) : 0
```

Or else you may use anything else than 0, that way tables will not disturbed.

Comment: Thanks. The logs have the hours and project_id as fields. The problem is that when I make a loop on the hash it only goes four times in this case. Three times for the first project an one time for the second. And hours is alwas present. It does not know that there is 7 days in a week.

Comment: Or just time_diff(hours) || 0